# Changing Visual C++ Compilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I've been looking around and have probably just not been able to put the right terms in my search, since I don't know what this would be called. I skimmed over building interpreters, but I don't think that's what I want.

Lets say I wanted to use C++'s basic syntax in Visual C++ (2010, if it really matters), but compile it into my own format. So I'd take:

```
if(myVar == 1)
```

And instead of letting VC++ assemble it, I could somehow override that (without having to build my own damn compiler) to my own byte code like this:

```
1F00EE01
```

Where in my imaginary byte code language, 1F represents IF, 00 is the variable number (in some determined order of variables), EE is the operator 'equals' and 01 plays it's natural role.

Obviously it would get a bit more complex than that, but for now I'm just speculating. Just searching for any way to use VC++'s parsing of an already well-built language instead of creating my own and changing the result of compilation. Now that I write it down, the thought seems ridiculous, still, hopefully any responses will still be interesting enough though.

Comment: If you want to play with the compiler and see how it works, you'd be much better off with an open-source compiler like gcc.  But if you're interested in compilers and interpreters, I think you'd be better off finding a book or tutorial ... and trying your hand at just *writing* one.  MSVS is really a "black box" (and a very large, sophisticated and complex one at that!); open source compilers aren't as "black" - but can be every bit as large and complex.  Start small, start from scratch.  IMHO...

Comment: Trying to start small was the intention. I'm trying to not have to build a compiler (recognizing keywords, indention, values etc. all seems wayy too much for me). I was thinking that maybe 'overloading' an IF using #define as a macro (which I hear is possible) could turn it into a function, where I can write the code to write the right byte code (so kinda like building an app that compiles itself in another language). Functions would be easy. It's just keywords and operators that would be a pain to change.

Comment: You can tell Visual Studio to use any compiler you want, however there won't be any compiler where you can change the output format easily. Even if you use an open source and architecture like GCC, it will involve a _lot_ of coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSVC has a built in compiler and there is no way of changing that.

It has a list of possible target platforms that is not extendable either.

Comment: Right, well I guess I would be better off replacing cl.exe and building my own compiler from scratch then... But it just seems a bit too big of a task for me.

Comment: Write a few words on what do you want to achieve. New language? New target platform? Ex: I have my own compiler front end. Does this sound interesting?

Comment: I'm basically catering to a pre-existing bytecode parser in a game. It's pretty basic in reading a file byte-by-byte to determine what to do in/to the game. So we're not talking a programming language here. But a coding language that I want to be able to write in basic C++.

Comment: Does this mean that you wan to be able to translate some subset of C++ into your byte-code, that you are already able to interpret?

Comment: Please, drop me a line at http://www.cdsan.com/contacts.php. This is not a free product; at the same time I am opened for discussion.